# I want to create a csv column in my while loop that does not exist in SQL

Tags: php, sql

I want to create a csv column in my while loop that does not exist in SQL. My goal is to add all of the costs of cost1, cost2, cost3, cost4 and cost5, together and then output them as their own column titled "Total Cost" Here is my code.

```
<?php
    // output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=WaitingForStock.csv');

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('Product ID', 'Cost 1', 'Cost 2', 'Cost 3', 'Cost 4', 'Cost 5', 'Total Cost'));

// fetch the data
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password); // Connected
mysql_select_db($db_name); // Database selected
$rows = mysql_query('SELECT productnumber, cost1, cost2, cost3, cost4, cost5 FROM products'); // Query for only waiting for stock

// loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);


?>
```

Comment: `$row['total'] = $row['cost1'] + $row['cost2'] + $row['cost3'] + $row['cost4'] + $row['cost5'];` maybe?

Comment: @MarkBaker This would have likely been another solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add them together in your SQL statement:

```
SELECT productnumber, cost1, cost2, cost3, cost4, cost5, cost1+cost2+cost3+cost4+cost5 as total_cost FROM products;
```